# Two spheres capacitors

Tags: capacitor, physics

A capacitor consisting of two concentric spheres of radius R1 and R2 = 2.50·R1 has a capacitance of C = 6.00 picoFarads and is charged to a potential difference of 74.0 Volts.

1. Calculate the energy stored in the capacitor.
2. Calculate the charge on this capacitor, when the electrical energy stored is 19.9·10-8 Joules.
3. **If the radius of the outer sphere is increased by a factor of 3.00 while keeping the charge on the plates constant, by what factor does the stored energy change?**

I've already answered #1 and #2 Questions, but I don't know how to calculate the third one. Help please!

Comment: What are the formulas you found for #1? This is part of the solution for #3.

Comment: This sounds homeworkesque

Comment: If this is homework, you better mention this in your question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking a homework question, generally users are expected to show some work on their homework, but this user seems to have calculated 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

What you missing for part C is the formulae for the capacitance of two concentric spheres:
$$  C= \frac{4\pi\epsilon}{1/a - 1/b}$$  with  $$ b>a $$
From that you should be able to determine the ratio of C wrt the change in R

Answer (score 0):

Energy stored in a capacitor is: \$U = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{Q^2}{C}\$

You know the amount of charge.

What effect would tripling the radius of the outer "plate" of the capacitor have on the structure's capacitance?

Comment: @Kortuk - If he has calculated #1 he can calculate #3, it's a bit lazy... and the fact it's obviously "please do my homework for me" makes it doubly so.

Comment: My point, which I am worrying I am not making clear, is the user knows how to solve the first 2 parts but not the third, and this just reads as restating it. However, I remember when I have had to restate a question before to have a student understand it, so I will remove the -1.